# Selenium: find element by visible Text

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

In the html page i have the following balise:

```
<button class="....." data-toggle="dropdown">
Text: Title of the button                        
<span class="....."/>
</button>
```

And I want to detect this buton By the visible text **Text: Title of the button** the problem is that i'm trying to detect it using the following Xpath

```
.//*[contains(text(),"Text: Title of the button")]
```

But it does'nt work.
How i can detect this button?

**FYI:** I can't detect it using `class` because there more than one matching node with this class.

Comment: Try //*[contains(text(),"Text: Title of the button")][0] or share me the code.

Comment: Please see whether that text comes inside the button tags. If yes check the part of the text //button[contains(text(),'Part of Title of the button')]

Comment: @IAH2iV You can see the code of the HTML above, this Text comes Inside the button tags, but the problem that button contains an other balise Inside.

Comment: @Kichan Patel, the problem is not with more matching node for the XPATH the problem that XPATH don't match with any node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contains(text(), '...')` only evaluates *first text node child* from current context element. This shouldn't be any problem for sample element you posted (see [demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/f2fbac9f22a0162175be1896115858ce), but it wouldn't work with the following element for example, because the first text node inside `button` is the newline located before `span` :

```
<button class="....." data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="....."/>
Text: Title of the button                        
</button>
```

To evaluate *all* text node children of current context element, use the following form instead :

```
.//*[text()[contains(.,"Text: Title of the button")]]
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/90dd72533ddfebd3484fe828860f03e4)</kbd>**

The above XPath tests individual text node if it contains certain text.

Answer (score 1):

Hi please do it like below

```
By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Text: Title of the button')]")
please put Text: Title of the button in single quote.
Also if more html source code is provided then i can come up with a better locator stratgey
```

Also you can do it on the basis of Class name as well or by talking attribute
data-toggle="dropdown" in xpath as well like //*[@data-toggle='dropdown']

// take class name of the button in list

```
List<WebElement> buttons= driver.findElements(By.className("className"));
Now you can select your concerned button on the basis of index (in java index starts 
form zero)
```

Comment: In fact my question is is-there onother way to detect element By innner Text except  Contains(text()," ") because all the other solution are not the better way in my case.There are more than 12 matching node with Class and more than 10 matching node with data-toggle, I have more than 5 button and I want to detect them with general solution based on the visible text.

Comment: ok plz confirm By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Text: Title of the button')]") this line worked or not

Comment: No this line doesn't work i have tried before!. I have examples with no balise Inside the element , only the text and it work but in my cas no.

Comment: can you post a complete source code of your problem area

Comment: Sorry, the source code is confidential and i can't post it. Thank you for your help.